# Imitate Prolog's Backtracking in Racket

Tags: macros, prolog, scheme, racket

I find Prolog's backtracking quite fascinating and was wondering if anyone has any possible ideas on how one could imitate Prolog's backtracking in Racket, as a possible summer project idea. Also, why is Racket macros so powerful?

Comment: You can implementing backtracking search in any programming language, though languages with first class functions make it much easier.  You may find looking into continuation passing style helpful.  But, as it is posed, this question is really too vague or broad for Stack Overflow.  If you're just looking for references, then it's probably off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A blast from the past "Transliterating Prolog into Scheme", Mathias Felleisen, 1982.

ftp://infosecon.net/pub/techreports/TR182.pdf

Also, get your hands on "The Reasoned Schemer".

https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/reasoned-schemer

Comment: link that worked for me (today): ftp://ftp.extreme.indiana.edu/pub/techreports/TR182.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Alas, you may not be entirely delighted to hear that this package already exists. It's called Racklog, and it was initially developed by Dorai Sitaram. Here's the documentation:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/racklog/index.html?q=racklog

Answer (score 3):

As it has not been mentioned yet, there is [a meta-circular implementation](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-28.html#%25_sec_4.3) in the *Structure and Implementation of Computer programs* by Abelson and Sussman, which runs a code by converting it into *two*-continuations [passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), with the passing of two  continuations throughout, one for *success* and the other for *failure*.